# "more activity" why singular?

Tags: grammatical-number, agreement

I came across this sentence while reading an article:

"The massive, untracked streams of cash it creates can fuel **more illegal activity**, including terrorism."

It seems weird to me that the word "more" was used with the singular form of "activity."
Wouldn't it make more sense to say "more illegal activit**ies**"?
Or is the word "activity" more used as a singular noun than a plural noun?

I would greatly appreciate any help! Thanks! :)

Comment: Is it wrong to say 'more activities'?  I don't think so.

Comment: I think the meanings of *activity* that applies here is "the state or quality of being active" - there is more illegal activity in the sense that criminals are more active in the situation in question. (Not sure that that's enough to post as an answer, but it might get you started.)

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, ‘activity’ designates a body of actions undertaken by somebody and is uncountable. Uncountable nouns refer to actions/objects collectively. A few examples of phrases with the same characteristics: police work/activity, physical exercise, manual work, good advice, etc. We can use determinants such as more/less, intense/mild, better/worse in relation to such words, but we cannot exactly say how much or how many of ‘it’ somebody has done/undergone, etc.
‘Activity’ may be countable or uncountable, but there are many nouns that are uncountable only, whether defective of singular or of plural.
According to https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/activity (visited on 05/11/2020), activity means: def. B2 [uncountable] “the situation in which a lot of things are happening or people are moving around: […] Economists are concerned by the low level of **economic activity**”; def. B2 [countable & uncountable] “the work of a group or organization to achieve an aim: He was found guilty of **terrorist activity**”.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please see [Your answer is in another castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370). Answers should be **complete in themselves,** albeit referencing supporting works.

Comment: Both links go to the same limited definition. Answers that use *maybe* hint at opinion, albeit wonderful. The OP is a singular-plural question. Can you expand to explain why *acitivites* is not needed?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, **Activity** can be countable or uncountable.

In its uncountable form, it encompasses all types of activity; activity in general:

*"The building site was a hive of activity."*

In its countable form, it refers to separate/individual activities:

*"The carpenters, builders, plasterers and roofers were busily engaged in their activities."*

[Collins Dictionary: Activity/activity](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english)

> **1. uncountable noun**
>
> Activity is a situation in which a lot of things are happening or being done.
>
> ...an extraordinary level of activity in the government bonds market.
>
> ***...the electrical activity of the brain.* [+ of]**
>
> 2. countable noun
>
> **An activity is something that you spend time doing.**
>
> *You can take part in activities from canoeing to bird watching.*
>
> When an uncountable noun is qualified by an adjective or adjunct, it may accept the indefinite article in its meaning of "an example of".

Consider:

"Ask John, he has *more* knowledge of the area *[than me]*"

And thus we have:

[It] can fuel *more* illegal activity (uncountable) *[than I have mentioned]*